# NoSuchMethodError on tomcat with vaadin spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

When I try to run my vaadin spring application on a tomcat server, I get the following Error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet springVaadinServlet threw exception
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1256) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:694) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:358) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:133) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:831) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.18]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.addSessionInitListener(Lcom/vaadin/server/SessionInitListener;)V
at com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet.servletInitialized(SpringVaadinServlet.java:67) ~[vaadin-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:235) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.7.jar:8.0.7]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.18]
... 59 common frames omitted
```

When I generate a war file and start it local via tomcat, everything works fine. Why can the method in the exception above not be found, when I run this war-file on server? I'm working with eclipse, gradle and vaadin 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin Spring 1.x is not compatible with Vaadin Framework 8.x Either upgrade Vaadin Spring to version 2.1 or downgrade Vaadin Framework to 7.x.

Comment: I upgraded my spring to 2.0, but now my application is using vaadin-server-7.7.5.jar instead of 8.0.7 and throws the same Exception. I have two different versions of vaadin-server.jar in my project dependencies. What do I have to remove in my gradle setup to delete one of them?

Comment: I don't know very much about Gradle, but https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies seems to describe how you can figure out the reason for various dependencies being included in an application.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason could be, that your server is not cleaned between deployments, and hence there are multiple versions of same jars, and classloader fails.

Comment: Indeed  ihave two version of server-vaadin.jar, but I don't know how to remove one of them. I can't do it manually in the build settings of projects properties. I guess I have to remove it in gradle.

Comment: I would assume you can access the server folders and delete the files and re-deploy. Do you have "clean" step configured in your Gradle setup, I mean similar to "mvn clean"? That is necessary to perform when updating versions, so that no duplicate jars is ending in packaged war file.